# Suspension bouncing left and right

Tags: honda, suspension, acura, suspension-geometry

I have a 1995 Acura legend and it was a project car to replace all suspension parts, bushings etc. basically I started with the rear suspension, replaced everything there including struts and bushings and then moved to the front. Due to complications it took us nearly 2 years to complete the front suspension, in which the rears were on jack stands to hold the pressure off the struts. Now (after an alignment) the rears are like 4 inches lower than the front which have oem springs, and there isn’t body roll left and right, the whole rear bounces from left to right after a bump is hit. The control arms and tie rods were also replaced so they couldn’t be bent, so what’s the problem?

Comment: If your rear is 4 inches lower than the front then you have a serious problem somewhere, either the components used are wrong or something is drastically wrong with the setup.

Comment: I'm wondering if you didn't put spacers or pockets in the rear suspension?

Comment: I mean unless there was spacers oem I didn’t put any, just reorder oem shocks and put them on... I couldn’t see if it had spacers before because it had some aftermarket coil overs on it before I started the project

Answer (score 1):

The rear suspension fixings should only be finally tightened when the weight was on the wheels...

If you tightened them with the suspension fully extended then you « pre-load » all the bushes causing a different suspension response.

You could try releasing the bolts - wobbling the car side to side and then retightening the bolts / nuts.

Comment: Would that fix the problem of the car being too low you think? Or once the springs are compressed (if they are) it’s impossible to reverse that?

Comment: If you allow the bushes to re-set then see, because as others point out there may be other issues...

Comment: Alright I’ll check up the whole suspension later today so I don’t kill myself lol, thank you for the help!